# Memory issues with a list of lists

Tags: python, list, memory, memory-management

I am having some memory issues and I am wondering if there is any way I can free up some memory in the code below. I have tried using a generator expression rather than list comprehension but that does not produce unique combinations, as the memory is freed up.

The list of lists (combinations) causes me to run out of memory and the program does not finish.

The end result would be 729 lists in this list, with each list containing 6 `WindowsPath` elements that point to images. I have tried storing the lists as strings in a text file but I can not get that to work, I tried using a `pandas` `dataframe` but I can not get that to work.

I need to figure out a different solution. The output right now is exactly what I need but the memory is the only issue.

```
from pathlib import Path
from random import choice
from itertools import product
from PIL import Image
import sys

def combine(arr):
    return list(product(*arr))

def generate(x):

    #set new value for name
    name = int(x)

    #Turn name into string for file name
    img_name = str(name)

    #Pick 1 random from each directory, add to list.
    a_paths = [choice(k) for k in layers]

    #if the length of the list of unique combinations is equal to the number of total combinations, this function stops
    if len(combinations) == len(combine(layers)):
        print("Done")
        sys.exit()

    else:
        #If combination exists, generate new list
        if any(j == a_paths for j in combinations) == True:
            print("Redo")
            generate(name)

        #Else, initialize new image, paste layers + save image, add combination to list, and generate new list
        else:
            #initialize image
            img = Image.new("RGBA", (648, 648))
            png_info = img.info

            #For each path in the list, paste on top of previous, sets image to be saved
            for path in a_paths:
                layer = Image.open(str(path), "r")
                img.paste(layer, (0, 0), layer)

            print(str(name) + ' - Unique')
            img.save(img_name + '.png', **png_info)
            combinations.append(a_paths)
            name = name - 1
            generate(name)

'''
Main method
'''
global layers
layers = [list(Path(directory).glob("*.png")) for directory in ("dir1/", "dir2/", "dir3/", "dir4/", "dir5/", "dir6/")]

#name will dictate the name of the file output(.png image) it is equal to the number of combinations of the image layers
global name
name = len(combine(layers))

#combinations is the list of lists that will store all unique combinations of images
global combinations
combinations = []

#calling recursive function
generate(name)
```

Comment: It appears that the problem lies outside of the code you've posted.  Where are `layers` and `combinations` generated?  What does `combine` do?  What is the overall purpose of this code?  If you're trying to go through all possible combinations, you can use one of `itertools`'s generators to provide that.  If you need to do the random-generation technique, you can probably avoid dupes by storing hashes instead of the whole whatever-it-is, but without knowing the types of the values you're working with it's hard to suggest how you'd do that.

Comment: @Samwise I added the rest of the code. Apologies for not specifying. I will clarify some things. The overall purpose of this code is to randomly choose 1 image from each directory (dir1, dir2, dir3, etc.) and paste each image on top of each other. There are 3 images in each directory that is able to be chosen. The images are randomly selected and then compared with the list called "combinations", if the combination of selected images exists, it calls the function again. If not, it adds the combination (which is a list) to the list called "combinations" and calls the function again.

Comment: @Samwise another update, I tried doing b_paths = hash(str(a_paths)), b_paths = str(b_paths), then comparing the hashes and storing the hashes in the list. Same result, function cuts itself off after my memory clogs up to about 80% RAM used. I get about 95% of the way there. If there is a way I can clear up some memory that is being stored or override my memory usage to allow for a bit more before cutting off I would be able to finish the output.

Comment: So it looks like you're iterating until you've generated each possible combination in the list.  **Why don't you just iterate through the combinations instead of saving them as a list and then generating random combinations to rediscover them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a MRE version of your code (i.e. something that I can run without needing a bunch of PNGs -- all we're concerned with here is how to go through the images without hitting recursion limits):

```
from random import choice
from itertools import product


def combine(arr):
    return list(product(*arr))


def generate(x):

    # set new value for name
    name = int(x)

    # Turn name into string for file name
    img_name = str(name)

    # Pick 1 random from each directory, add to list.
    a_paths = [choice(k) for k in layers]

    # if the length of the list of unique combinations is equal to the number of total combinations, this function stops
    if len(combinations) == len(combine(layers)):
        print("Done")
        return

    else:
        # If combination exists, generate new list
        if any(j == a_paths for j in combinations) == True:
            print("Redo")
            generate(name)

        # Else, initialize new image, paste layers + save image, add combination to list, and generate new list
        else:
            # initialize image
            img = []

            # For each path in the list, paste on top of previous, sets image to be saved
            for path in a_paths:
                img.append(path)

            print(str(name) + ' - Unique')
            print(img_name + '.png', img)
            combinations.append(a_paths)
            name = name - 1
            generate(name)


'''
Main method
'''
global layers
layers = [
    [f"{d}{f}.png" for f in ("foo", "bar", "baz", "ola", "qux")]
    for d in ("dir1/", "dir2/", "dir3/", "dir4/", "dir5/", "dir6/")
]


# name will dictate the name of the file output(.png image) it is equal to the number of combinations of the image layers
global name
name = len(combine(layers))

# combinations is the list of lists that will store all unique combinations of images
global combinations
combinations = []

# calling recursive function
generate(name)
```

When I run this I get some output that starts with:

```
15625 - Unique
15625.png ['dir1/qux.png', 'dir2/bar.png', 'dir3/bar.png', 'dir4/foo.png', 'dir5/baz.png', 'dir6/foo.png']
15624 - Unique
15624.png ['dir1/baz.png', 'dir2/qux.png', 'dir3/foo.png', 'dir4/foo.png', 'dir5/foo.png', 'dir6/foo.png']
15623 - Unique
15623.png ['dir1/ola.png', 'dir2/qux.png', 'dir3/bar.png', 'dir4/ola.png', 'dir5/ola.png', 'dir6/bar.png']
...
```

and ends with a `RecursionError`.  I assume this is what you mean when you say you "ran out of memory" -- in reality it doesn't seem like I'm anywhere close to running out of memory (maybe this would behave differently if I had actual images?), but Python's stack depth is finite and this function seems to be recursing into itself arbitrarily deep for no particularly good reason.

Since you're trying to eventually generate all the possible combinations, you already have a perfectly good solution, which you're even already using -- `itertools.product`.  All you have to do is iterate through the combinations that it gives you.  You don't need recursion and you don't need global variables.

```
from itertools import product
from typing import List


def generate(layers: List[List[str]]) -> None:
    for name, a_paths in enumerate(product(*layers), 1):
        # initialize image
        img = []

        # For each path in the list, paste on top of previous,
        # sets image to be saved
        for path in a_paths:
            img.append(path)

        print(f"{name} - Unique")
        print(f"{name}.png", img)

    print("Done")


'''
Main method
'''
layers = [
    [f"{d}{f}.png" for f in ("foo", "bar", "baz", "ola", "qux")]
    for d in ("dir1/", "dir2/", "dir3/", "dir4/", "dir5/", "dir6/")
]

# calling iterative function
generate(layers)
```

Now we get all of the combinations -- the naming starts at 1 and goes all the way to 15625:

```
1 - Unique
1.png ['dir1/foo.png', 'dir2/foo.png', 'dir3/foo.png', 'dir4/foo.png', 'dir5/foo.png', 'dir6/foo.png']
2 - Unique
2.png ['dir1/foo.png', 'dir2/foo.png', 'dir3/foo.png', 'dir4/foo.png', 'dir5/foo.png', 'dir6/bar.png']
3 - Unique
3.png ['dir1/foo.png', 'dir2/foo.png', 'dir3/foo.png', 'dir4/foo.png', 'dir5/foo.png', 'dir6/baz.png']
...
15623 - Unique
15623.png ['dir1/qux.png', 'dir2/qux.png', 'dir3/qux.png', 'dir4/qux.png', 'dir5/qux.png', 'dir6/baz.png']
15624 - Unique
15624.png ['dir1/qux.png', 'dir2/qux.png', 'dir3/qux.png', 'dir4/qux.png', 'dir5/qux.png', 'dir6/ola.png']
15625 - Unique
15625.png ['dir1/qux.png', 'dir2/qux.png', 'dir3/qux.png', 'dir4/qux.png', 'dir5/qux.png', 'dir6/qux.png']
Done
```

Replacing the actual image-generating code back into my mocked-out version is left as an exercise for the reader.

If you wanted to randomize the order of the combinations, it'd be pretty reasonable to do:

```
from random import shuffle

...

    combinations = list(product(*layers))
    shuffle(combinations)
    for name, a_paths in enumerate(combinations, 1):
        ...
```

This uses more memory (since now you're building a `list` of the product instead of iterating through a generator), but the number of images you're working with isn't actually that large, so this is fine as long as you aren't adding a level of recursion for each image.

Comment: This is definitely the solution I was looking for, keeping the images in memory due to the recursion was definitely the issue. I appreciate it a lot and you are my savior! The shuffle package was definitely what I was hoping to include! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Just wondering also, do you know if there is any way to be have 1 of the images from the directories show up in a certain percentage of the output?

For example: Image 1 from dir1 is generated 60% of the time, Image 2 from dir1 is generated 30% of the time, and Image 3 from dir1 is generated in the remaining 10% of all outputted images.

Comment: If your intent is to generate all the combinations exhaustively, and not to have any repeats, that is by definition impossible.  You need to be willing to bend on one of those two requirements if you want to change the distribution as you describe.  :)

Comment: I thought so haha. Well, a little manual deletion should do the trick. I am forever grateful for your help

Comment: The tool that'll be useful to you is `random.choices`, specifically the `weights` parameter that lets you specify the percentages in one fell swoop  -- you just need to figure out whether you want to add extra images (which will be duplicates of existing images) or eliminate some.